# Twilio Call Issue from iOS App to Phone

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, phone-call

I am trying to make call from my app to phone, My app executes a POST Request in which i am passing following parameters.

```
 CallUrl     =  “https://api.twilio.com/2010-04- 01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json”

 From        = “+MyTwilioNumber”
 To          = “+9179XXXXXXXX”
 Url         = “myserveraddress.com/data.xml”
 AuthToken   = “cdXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”
 AccountSid  = “ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”
```

Url Returns-

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
         <Number>+9179XXXXXXXX</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Now what happens is that when call is received, I hear the number you are trying to call is busy.

Can anybody help me what’s going wrong ???

Also how can I get call status in my App like call is ringing, answered, disconnected ???

Comment: If it says the number you are trying to call is busy, then it sounds like the number you are trying to call is actually busy. Is it a number you know not to be busy?

Comment: I specified same number in TO parameter and in my Xml in Dial Verb. when call is received and what i hear is number is busy .  Url response again tells twilio to make call on that number , which is already busy . I think that might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds like you are making the call correctly and just dialling a busy number. If that's not the case, then let me know and I'll see if I can help further.

As for getting events for when the call is ringing, answered, disconnected etc, you need to check out the [`statusCallback` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter). You pass a URL to get webhooks when the statuses you want to hear about (chosen via the [`statusCallbackEvent` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-event-parameter) happen.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I specified same number in TO parameter and in my Xml in Dial Verb. when call is received and what i hear is number is busy .  Url response again tells twilio to make call on that number , which is already busy .

Can u please tell me what response actually url should return to make call . So two participants can communicate.

Comment: i just made a experiment , Different number in To and in xml example To = “NUMBER1” , in xml <Number> = “NUMBER2”.
No what happened is :  i made call from my iOS  App , call i received by NUMBER1 and as soon as call picked by NUMBER1, i received call on NUMBER2 and both are able to hear each other. can’t figure out what’s happening

Comment: Oh! Are you making the API call from your iOS app? Have you looked into the programmable voice API for iOS: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk

Comment: Yes, am i doing it in the wrong way ??  I checked sample app.

Comment: In the iOS app you should be using the iOS SDK to start calls, not the REST API. Perhaps you can share a bit more of what you've done so far?

Comment: Yes ,i am using REST API’s  in my iOS App .Messages can be sent successfully and received using API’s only facing issues while calling. Call  can be received but participants cannot communicate.

 I checked sample App delivered with iOS SDK. I need to setup my server first. So do u mean all cals will be handled by my server ??
 I will request from my App to Server then server will request to twilio for call .

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do, the iOS SDK will place a call with Twilio, which will then ask your server what to do with it. As for making REST API calls from your application, to do that you would need to embed your account credentials and an attacker could decompile your application and abuse your account. We recommend you do it all on a server, so that you protect your credentials. See how to here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html